# Implode() to make an array to string not working?

Tags: php, arrays, string, mysqli, implode

I am stuck with this for hours, trying to fix it, but my little knowledge of php is not being enough, so I am asking for your help.

**HTML**

```
        <input type="checkbox" name="type[]" value="type1">Type 1<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="type[]" value="type2">Type 2<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="type[]" value="type3">Type 3<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="type[]" value="type4">Type 4
```

**PHP validate (separate file)**

```
if (empty($_POST["type"])) {
    $typeErr = "This field is required";
} else {
    $type = array($_POST["type"]);
}
```

**PHP**

```
/*this is line 90*/ $type_string = implode(',', $type);

$sql = "INSERT INTO `table1`(`type`) VALUES ('$type_string')";
```

**Error**

```
 Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\example.php on line 90
```

It keeps telling me I am converting an array to string when I use implode, I have no idea what I am doing wrong, I just have several checkboxes, and the selected ones go to an array, then I implode that array to a string to be able to send it to the mysql database...

It is probably a stupid mistake, but I am fairly new to php and mysql, so... can anyone help me?

I wrote $type_string to $typestring, but the problem remains, the notice still happens...

Comment: `$type_string != $typestring`

Comment: replace array($_POST["type"]) by $_POST["type"]

Comment: what @JohnConde says $typestring should be $type_string or the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$type = array($_POST["type"]);
```

now contains an array with `0 => array`

So the implode is still trying to convert key 0 to a string.

Either

```
$type = (array) $_POST["type"];
```

Which is what i think you meant or

```
 /*this is line 90*/ $type_string = implode(',', $type[0]);
```

should fix it.

also make sure you defend against SQL injection

Comment: FINALLY, so thank you really, such a simple fix to something I was stuck for hours! Literally hours, I should have asked this here earlier... Oh well, thank you a lot, really, completely fixed it :)

Comment: I am going to accept this answer as soon as it allows me (gotta wait 5min)

Answer (score 0):

$POST["type"] is already array. In Your code You are creating array(array()) srtucture.
If You want to be sure You are working with array use

```
if(is_array($_POST["type"])){ $type=$_POST["type"] }
```

or cast to array by using

```
$type = (array)$_POST["type"];
```

then You are free to use implode
Good luck :)